# Reading strings into array with input check

Tags: c++

I have a string array, lets call it A[maxsize].

I have to read stuff into it with cin (I wrote a function to check if the entered data is correct, but it is basically cin). BUT! I must not let the user add the same data twice.

A[0]=G
A[1]=G

shouldn't be possible.

I have figured it out that I need 2 loops, a for and a while. Can anybody help with this?
I have tried several ways but my program crashed when asked for 2nd input...

Thanks.

Comment: please post your code, and tell where is the problem.

Comment: We won't write code for you. We will tell you the errors you made in your code.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.

This seems to work:
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Please give the " << i << ". number: ";
            cin >> A[i];
        } while(A[i]==A[i-1]);

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing:

```
const size_t N = 10;
char s[N];

size_t i = 0;
char c;

while ( i < N && std::cout << "Enter a character: " && std::cin >> c )
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while ( j < i && s[j] != c ) j++;

    if ( j == i )
    {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Array already contains character " << c << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Try again." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, why do you use std:: before endl, cin, etc?

Answer (score 0):

How about validating the user's input each time they enter something new? This might help you get started:

```
bool isValidUserInput(string s, vector<string> saved) {
  for (int i = 0; i < saved.size(); ++i) {
    // compare every element in the collection (saved) against your new input (s).
    // if duplicate found, return false. Otherwise, return true.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in class we did not learn about this kind of stuff (I'm not talking about functions) and I have to write a user documentation also for the application, so if I code it this way, I have to know how does this work (vector and stufF).